# FEventTypeValue running before FEventTypeChildAdded

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm looking at the [Firechat demo project](https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios/blob/master/Firechat/ViewController.m#L54), and they use a technique whereas they're using `FEventTypeChildAdded` as well as `FEventTypeValue` as the latter will fire just after `FEventTypeChildAdded`. This is done in order to prevent a "spam" of `FEventTypeChildAdded` callbacks to avoid a UI lockup. However, I implemented the same technique in my app, but `FEventTypeValue` is actually called before `FEventTypeChildAdded`, resulting in the `BOOL` changing to `NO` and locking the UI.

From the demo project:

```
// This allows us to check if these were messages already stored on the server
// when we booted up (YES) or if they are new messages since we've started the app.
// This is so that we can batch together the initial messages' reloadData for a perf gain.
__block BOOL initialAdds = YES;

[self.firebase observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    // Add the chat message to the array.
    if (newMessagesOnTop) {
        [self.chat insertObject:snapshot.value atIndex:0];
    } else {
        [self.chat addObject:snapshot.value];
    }

    // Reload the table view so the new message will show up.
    if (!initialAdds) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];

// Value event fires right after we get the events already stored in the Firebase repo.
// We've gotten the initial messages stored on the server, and we want to run reloadData on the batch.
// Also set initialAdds=NO so that we'll reload after each additional childAdded event.
[self.firebase observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    // Reload the table view so that the intial messages show up
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    initialAdds = NO;
}];
```

Comment: To clarify (and you may know this). This method is not done to prevent lockups - it prevents reloading the tableView after every child added event when the children are first loaded. After they are finished loading (the first time) the tableView reloads, and then reloads for each child added after that. The code will work either way but calling reloadTableView repeatedly can add a lot of unnecessary overhead. Your issue may be elsewhere as I copied and pasted your code and it works.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, I know - I'm doing this in a chat VC, and inserting tableView rows extremely fast and repeatedly makes it stutter and unresponsive. Though thanks for adding the clarification! I'll take a deeper look at it and try to figure if the problem might be something else